GRPC circular dependencies in Bazel
I have several dependencies that pull in grpc and the circular dependency errors in Bazel are making it impossible to make progress at a reasonable pace. Most recently I started getting this error:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.grpc.internal.ServerImplBuilder
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
    ... 3 more

So I added the grpc-core v1.60 as a dependency and it started to throw this error:
    @@grpc//:io_grpc_grpc_all (e78a2bcb...)
    @@grpc//:io_grpc_grpc_xds (e78a2bcb...)
    @@grpc//:io_grpc_grpc_services (e78a2bcb...)
.-> @@grpc//:io_grpc_grpc_util (e78a2bcb...)
|   @@grpc//:io_grpc_grpc_core (e78a2bcb...)
`-- @@grpc//:io_grpc_grpc_util (e78a2bcb...)

I have tried adjusting versions though, based on the hash which I assume is related to a build version, this cycle seems to only use the same version.
I moved grpc to its own repo like this:
maven_install(
    name = "grpc",
    artifacts = [
        "io.grpc:grpc-all:1.60.0",
    ],
    fetch_sources = True,
    repositories = [
        "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2",
        "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact",
    ],
)

I've experimented with exclusions like this:
 maven.artifact(
            artifact = "grpc-core",
            exclusions = [
                "io.grpc:grpc-util",
            ],
            group = "io.grpc",
            version = "1.60.0",
        ),

and I've experimented with the override rule to always use a fixed version. Nothing has really worked and I just can't believe Bazel doesn't have better tooling to fix this.

Did you try using http_archive to load gRPC from its source repository directly? https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/cpp/README.md#bazel
This way, Bazel will use the dependencies specified within the archive, which may help with circular dependency issues.
